# Socket JS not works inside onload method

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets

I have this js piece which I use for django channels:

```
 var chatSocketSender1 = new WebSocket(
    'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/my_socket1/'
)

function send() {
    var msg =  "some message"
    var receiver_id = 111
    window['chatSocketSender1'].send( JSON.stringify({
        'msg': msg,
        'receiver_id': receiver_id
    }) )
}

document.querySelector('#send_button').onclick = function() {
      send();
}
```

The problem  is that this js code only works if I put that after latest element of HTML:

```
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    // whole html content here
    <script>
        // js piece here
    </script>
</body>
```

But if I use jquery's on load method like:

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            // js piece here

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    // whole html content here
</body>
```

Then it gives: `Uncaught TypeError: window[("chatSocketSender1")] is undefined`

Any suggestion please, why this not works with "onload" ?

Comment: The `load` just means "run this after all scripts have been downloaded". You still have to think about the order of execution.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier - So js code inside `load` and js code at the end of HTML, are not exactly same ? I thought they were equivalent. no ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze they are equivalent, only one is at the `window` (global) level and the other is scoped in the callback.  So your `var xxx` cannot be referenced as `window.xxx` as it's not a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because in your first code `var chatSocketSender1` creates a "global" variable (that's defined at the `window` level) that you later reference as `window("chatSocketSender1")`, but in the second code, `var chatSocketSender1` is scoped to the anonymous event handler function, so is not available as `window("chatSocketSender1")`.

Put another way:

```
<script>
var x = 1;
function foo() {
 console.log(x)
}
</script>
```

works fine, but

```
<script>
function foo() {
  var x = 1;
}
foo();
console.log(x);
</script>
```

will give an undefined variable error as `x` only exists inside `foo`.  This isn't exactly what you've done, but is essentially the same concept.

Now, if your code was:

```
chatSocketSender1.send(
```

then it would have worked fine as your variable `chatSocketSender1` is defined within the `function() {` onload event callback.

or instead of

```
var chatSocketSender1 =
```

you could do

```
window.chatSocketSender1 =
```

to define the variable globally, *or* you could:

```
<script>
var chatSocketSender1 = new WebSocket(...
function send() { ... }
$(window).on('load', function () {
  document.querySelector('#send_button').onclick = ...
```

as you generally only need the event binding within the onload.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works using `window.chatSocketSender1 = `